# How to set a valid SPF record with a microsoft azure server?

Tags: azure, spf

I'm trying to setup a SPF record on Microsoft Azure, because currently our emails are considered as spam.

This is the record I've added:

[image: TXT record]

But it doesn't seem to work, since https://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html returns this when I test the SPF record for my domain:

```
SPF record lookup and validation for: check-in.green

SPF records are published in DNS as TXT records.

The TXT records found for your domain are:
fidelise-rpfc.azurewebsites.net 

Checking to see if there is a valid SPF record. 

No valid SPF record found of either type TXT or type SPF.
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That `@.check-in.green` record name doesn't look right. If you're trying to set it for the domain as a whole (which you should be), that record name should be just `@`, which is shorthand for "this domain".

Comment: are you trying (or have already) set up a VM in Azure as an external mail server? If so, as far as I know this is still not allowed. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresecurity/2016/08/16/pro-tip-on-sending-email-from-azure-virtual-machines-to-external-domains/

Comment: @Synchro That's the default name my record gets if I leave the field blank or if I type @ inside. Can't seem to get rid of the ".check-in.green", not sure if I did something wrong.

Comment: @silent we don't have that as far as I know. But sending emails definitely works, we do that all the time, only problem is they end up being treated as spam, notably because of the SPF thing.

Comment: What do you mean? You are sending emails but do not have an smtp server? How then? If you’re not sure you should clarify this as otherwise you might be in violation of the terms of use of Azure.

Comment: @silent any idea how I can check that? I don't have much knowledge in that regard and I didn't setup that stuff myself (and it's not documented). Where can I see if an smtp server was setup? Thanks for help

Comment: I cannot help you with that as I have no idea what your setup is. But since you have neither, I strongly recommend you take two steps back! Think what you actually want to achieve and then try to understand where you are currently at. This seems far broader than a SO question about SPF.

Answer (score 0):

It might be marked as SPAM not just because of SPF record but because of DMARC & DKIM as well.
If you are using 3rd party mail delivery provider - check their dash board for values. If you are sending emails yourself directly, here is a my cheat sheet:

1) **DNS _dmarc record**:

`TXT/_dmarc/v=DMARC1; p=none; fo=1; rua=mailto:dmarc_agg@check-in.green; ruf=mailto:dmarc_afrf@check-in.green`

2) **DNS spf record**: your is fine

`TXT/@/v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de ~all`

but usually you have to specify only one type of outbound ip address (you can check IP in actual messages that been delivered, e.g. Gmail have 'show original' option on email):
**a** - when you send from IP that can be resolved as A record (check-in.green web server itself)
**mx** - when you send from the same IP as in your MX record (if you have dedicated mail server for incoming emails and the same server sends outgoing for your project)
**includes** - usually for 3rd party mail delivery services, like mailgun etc. So, receiver will continue query for another record until it get a full list of IP or until 10 queries made.
**ip4:xx.xx.xx.xx** - when you have specific IPs for your outgoing relays (or your web servers have dedicated interface for this to avoid exposing real server address behind CDN)

3) **DNS DKIM record**: generate an RSA key pair (e.g. http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/)
Set the public part to your DNS record:

`TXT/rec1._domainkey/v=DKIM1; p=MIIBITANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQE....TsddAgMBAAE==`

4) Make sure you message have **DKIM-Signature header** made with private key and marked s=rec1 (as in DNS DKIM record).

Also, do not forget to check your message in test recipient mailbox (e.g. gmail). Here you can check if all 3 validation are passed:

you are using azure, so, keep in mind they can block outgoing SMTP or redirrect via their own servers
[image]